# Crear un objeto en tiempo de ejecución en Java

Tags: java

Me gustaría crear una función a la que se pasa un `String` como parámetro y esta llame al constructor de una clase y cree un objeto de esta con el nombre que se le ha pasado por parámetro.

Aquí os dejo un ejemplo de la función:

```
void crearobjeto(String _nombre) {
    Miembro _nombre =new Miembro() {
    };
```

La idea es que si luego llamas a la función pasándole el parámetro "miembro1" te cree un objeto de la clase miembro llamado miembro1

Gracias

Comment: la idea es que si luego llamas a la funcion pasandole el parametro "miembro1" te cree un objeto de la clase miembro llamado miembro1

Comment: ¿El objetivo o necesidad de esto cuál sería? En principio creo que no es posible.

Comment: que el usuario pueda crear los objetos que quiera sin necesidad de haberlos tenido que crear en el main inicialmente

Comment: Pero es que la posibilidad de crear objetos en tiempo de ejecución no pasa por el nombre de la variable. Agrega el código donde muestres que harías con estos objetos una vez creados para tratar de encontrar alguna solución.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer, es agregar un atributo en la clase Miembro, en la cual se le asigne el nombre del objeto. Y por cierto, los objetos en java se crean en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: @MrDave1999 lo que quiere es que la variable que tiene la referencia al objeto se llame de acuerdo al valor de un `String` que pase como parámetro.

Comment: @E.Betanzos El problema es que el nombre del puntero que guarda la referencia del objeto solo existe en tiempo de compilación.

Comment: @MrDave1999 los objetos no tienen nombre, sino una dirección en memoria la cual es manejada por las variables. Lo que se pide es que el nombre de la variable se defina en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: No, los nombres de las variables existen desde tiempo de compilación.

Comment: en mi programa debe haber muchos objetos de la clase miembro,por eso busco una opcion en la que el usuario pueda ejecutar una funcion en la que crear un objeto y añadir sus atributos (tantas veces como quiera)y  de ese modo evitar poner 30(o las que sean) llamadas al constructor en el main,el nombre de los objetos tampoco es relevante

Comment: @user109606 Si vas a tener muchos objetos y no sabes cuantos, podrías hacer uso de un [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: @MrDave1999 muchas gracias, eso es lo que estaba buscando

Comment: Realmente no le veo mucho sentido a centrarte en **el nombre de la variable**. A no ser que esto tenga alguna relevancia en tu contexto, si es así quizá convendría que lo expliques. Si por algún motivo necesitas que el objeto esté identificado por el dato que es pasado como `String` podrías hacerlo a través de una propiedad de la misma clase.

Comment: Justo aprendiendo y me hice la misma pregunta y me hice un codigo el cual no funciono. Voy a dejar un comentario sobre este post y aclarar un poco mas de que se trata la intencion que tengo que supongo es muy parecida a a del colega.
Tengo una clase Alumno con sus atrubutos, nombre,dni,correo.
Quiero preguntar por consola si quiere ingresar un nuevo alumno. 1 Si, 0 No.
Ingreso en el ciclo. Si es afirmativo tengo que instanciar un objeto tipo clase, luego setear cada uno de sus atributos. Todo pedido por consola. Ingrese el nombre, ingrese el dni y luego correo. una vez que esto sucedio, lo alm